# Building walls to correct channelized flow in ArcHydro

Tags: arc-hydro, rivers

My current project entails burning in a known river network into a high resolution (10x10m) DEM. In doing so, I'm attempting to build walls to correct for channelized flow in the DEM, in order to eventually execute the flow direction and flow accumulation tools. 
I've identified two areas where there are man-made channels that don't follow the DEM. In these places, I created a polygon shapefile for "Inner Walls" and a polyline shapefile for "breakthrough lines" to put in the Build Walls tool.
In the photo below, I depict an initial flow accumulation DEM in blue just to show why I'm building the walls here.

[image: Wall Polygons in purple on DEM with River Polyline in red and Initial Flow Accumulation from DEM in blue]

Yet, I keep getting this error below and am not sure what steps to take to resolve it. 
[image: Build walls error message from ArcGIS]

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved with a simple code in the Raster Calculator to eliminate NoData values that were being read as strings. 
However, I'm still encountering issues in that when I run the Build Walls function, the status bar fills to 100% in just a couple minutes and then it continues running for 30 hours or more without ever outputting a file. (I ultimately have to restart ArcMap each time this has happened).

It can't be an issue with the processing power of the P.C. Interested if anyone has ideas on how move forward.